# Accessing UI operations from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a "Share on Facebook" button in my app at 3 different view controllers. So I wrote a class which name is "ShareCentral" and i want to do all sharing operations in this class. But for showing share dialog i need to pass uiviewcontroller to my ShareCentral class. I did like that:

```
class ShareCentral {



    var UIVC: UIViewController


    init(vc:UIViewController) {
        self.UIVC = vc
    }

    func shareOnFacebook() {
        var content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string:userProfileLink)!)
        do {
            try ShareDialog.show(from: UIVC, content: content)
        }catch (let error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my view controller:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    let shareCentral = ShareCentral(vc: self)


    @IBAction func shareButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
          self.shareCentral.shareOnFacebook()
    }
}
```

I am getting following compiler error:

```
SettingsViewController.swift:40:41: Cannot convert value of type '(SettingsViewController) -> () -> (SettingsViewController)' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
```

I know if i change the type of UIVC to "SettingsViewController" the problem will disappear. But as i said before i am gonna use this method in three different view controllers.

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
class ShareCentral {
    unowned var UIVC: UIViewController

    init(vc:UIViewController) {
        self.UIVC = vc
    }

    func shareOnFacebook() {
        var content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string:userProfileLink)!)
        do {
            try ShareDialog.show(from: UIVC, content: content)
        } catch (let error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    var shareVC: ShareVC!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.shareVC = ShareVC(vc: self)
    }

    @IBAction func shareButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
          self.shareCentral.shareOnFacebook()
    }
}
```